# Using TWebBrowser for parsing HTML data

Tags: delphi, browser, html-parsing

I got an app that uses TWebBrowser component, and i have link to one site, that opens it using TWebBrowser using "for" statement, by example like this:

```
adoquery.sql.text = "select top 10 id from table1";
    adoquery.sql.open;
    adoquery.sql.first;

    while not adoquery.eof do 
    begin
        TwebBrowser.navigate("http://website1.com/php?id="+inttostr(id));
        adoquery.next;
    end;
```

When pages load complete ("OnNavigateComplete") i call a function that parse HTML of loaded TwebBrowserData, after that makes update in database, but it doesn't work. How can i update the data of database when calling method "OnNavigateComplete"?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me, but note that if you navigate `TWebBrowser` somewhere, it doesn't mean it's immediate. It takes some time. To be more precise, it takes the time until the browser is in `READYSTATE_COMPLETE` state, which means the document received all of its data.

Comment: The above code isn't valid Pascal or Delphi - you need to use `'single'` not `"double"` quotes. You also can't just use `id` like that - you should use either Fields[0].AsString (we know there is only one field), FindField() or least efficiently FieldByName(). FindField example:   `var IdFld: TField;...ADOQuery.Open; IdFld := AdoQuery.FindField('ID');  while not AdoQuery.Eof do begin TwebBrowser.navigate('http://website1.com/php?id=' + IdFld.AsString);`

Comment: What errors are you getting? There are five errors in the above code: 1. Use of double quotes. 2. Using ADOQuery.SQL.Open and ADOQuery.SQL.First instead of ADOQuery.Open;. The (attempted) call to First is redundant. Newly opened queries are already on the first record. 3. You need to get the value of ID using **fieldexpr**.AsString. 4. You need to use an instance of TWebBrowser, not call `Navigate` from TWebBrowser - it isn't a class (static) method. 5. Using the quality operator `=` instead of the assignment operator `:=`

Comment: Using a visual browser to perform an HTTP GET is way over the top. Use `IdHTTP` or similar.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it depends, sometimes you need to access the DOM for easier data extraction.